# Aura : Method issue ; Not able to call aura method

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have written the below code where in the  parent component, I have defined a lightning button to get the values from aura method defined in child component:
The lightning button in my parent component is not showing the alert pop up with the value from method.

Below is my code:

ChildComp:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:method name="child" action="{!c.handleChild}" access="public">
        <aura:attribute name="param1" type="String"/>
    </aura:method>
</aura:component>
```

ChildCompController:

```
({
    handleChild : function(component, event, helper) {
        var params = event.getParam('arguments');
        console.log("++++++++++",params);
        if(params){
            var param1=params.param1;
            alert(param1);
        }
    }
})
```

Parent Comp:

```
<aura:component >
    <c:ChildComp aura:id="childComp"/>
    <lightning:button name="Invoke Child action" label="Invoke Child action" onClick="{!c.doClick}"/>
</aura:component>
```

ParentCompController:

```
({
    doClick : function(cmp, event) {
        var cc=component.find('childComp');
        cc.child('I am from parent comp');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 Issues:

In parent component markup change `onClick` to `onclick`

```
<lightning:button name="Invoke Child action" label="Invoke Child action" onclick="{!c.doClick}"/>
```

In parent component controller: change component.find to cmp.find

```
doClick : function(cmp, event) {
var cc=cmp.find('childComp');
```

**Learning Suggestion:**
Also Since you are learning Try to troubleshoot these issues using [chrome dev tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) by putting breakpoints which will help you understand and fix these issues yourself

Comment: thanks, the main issue was onclick. i was using onClick that was causing the issue.